# ALT+ENTER Keyboard Shortcut to open Properties

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I am writing a winforms application and one of the functions is to open an item's properties. I'm not able to find out how to handle this. A menu item doesn't allow to define such a keyboard shortcut and implementing the handler manually with the keyup or keypress event handlers doesn't work either. Anyone out there who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Thomas is correct, you must use a `ToolStripMenuItem`. Adding the following line to my `.designer` file worked like a champ:

```
this.fileProperties.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Alt | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter;
```

The keystroke works and the `string` `Alt + Enter` is displayed on the menu item.

Comment: Never thought of that solution. Sometimes the simplest is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define such a shortcut on a `ToolStripMenuItem`, but not on a `MenuItem`

> implementing the handler manually with
>   the `keyup` or `keypress` event handlers
>   doesn't work either.

That's weird... can you show the code ?

Comment: i can dig out the code when I'm in the office again but the result was, that the menu in the menubar was selected as soon as the ALT key was pressed. Do you have some working code? Maybe I'm handling it in the wrong event handler...

Answer (score 0):

In the properties menu, you can just type "Alt+Enter" for the ShortcutKeys. However, it will view the Enter key as "(unknown)".